# What other data structure can I use to store a sequence of values and is immutable? How would this be fixed?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
room_numbers = {
    ['Freddie', 'Jen']: 403,
    ['Ned', 'Keith']: 391,
    ['Kristin', 'Jazzmyne']: 411,
    ['Eugene', 'Zach']: 395
}
```

Need this as in dictionary and can not find the solution....

Comment: Please provide more information on what it is you are trying to achieve, i.e. what you want to be fixed, so that we can help you.

Comment: I keep getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'... I would like to fix this issue so I can run the code properly...

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary keys must be immutable data type. You could use a tuple instead of a list as keys to the dictionary like :

```
dict_ = {
   ('Freddie', 'Jen'): 403,
   ('Ned', 'Keith'): 391,
   ('Kristin', 'Jazzmyne'): 411,
   ('Eugene', 'Zach'): 395
}
```

Comment: You can always delete a key, and create a new key which is mutable @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev ! example `del dct[('Freddie', 'Jen')]` and `dct['Freddie, 'Jen] = 403`